# Embedding localhost files on production server

Tags: php

```
<script src="http://localhost/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Will the code above cause problems if used in a production environment? I know loading scripts from localhost is an unsafe approach but this area of the site is heavily protected.

Comment: localhost means the user's computer, you cannot include files from the user's computer...

Comment: Hi, I'm aware. Would the code above work if the user's computer had a webserver running on localhost?

Comment: no, this is not possible, the browser will not allow this as this would cause a huge security problem. this would mean that any website can grab files from your computer if you have a running webserver

Comment: OMG i was wrong, it works (tested with images, scripts and CSS) :o For me, this is absolutely not secure !